# Angular using a service in a non component file

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have a library file product.data.ts which is a collection of exported data. I need to change an amount in this data based on a value returned by a featureManagement service. We use this service all the time and in any component we use standard DI and include it in the constructor.

How can I inject this service in this type of file without a constructor or class?

```
const productUpdateLDFlag = () => {
  // We can not use the below because the service needs to be injected, but I am not sure how to.
return this.featureManagement.getCurrentFlagValue(SwitchesProperty.productVersion);
};
```

rest of file

```
export const PRODUCTS_COMBINED: Array<Products> = [ProductA, ProductB, productUpdateLDFlag(), Product D]
```

How do I use DI to bring in the featureManagement service and use it in the data.ts file?

Answer (score 0):

µIf you are in an injection context, you can use `inject(MyService)`

The injection context can be provided by `EnvironmentInjector.runInContext()`.

Comment: Thanks @Matthieu Giegler, do you know of any documentation on provideInContext. I can't find anything helpful.

Comment: @Bwizard my bad, I was talking about `runInContext`

Comment: Thanks, we are not on Angular 14 yet and this looks like it has only just become available. Do you know of another way of achieving my outcome? Thanks